# Simple Node.js server can send messages - why would it throw an error with html?

Tags: node.js

**Node.js:** v10.16.0

**Operating System:** Windows 10

**Question:** My simple test server can send messages, but not html information.  Why would that be?

**Background:** The following simple server displays the message 'hello world' in the browser.  However when I check the Network tab in devtools I see an error regarding favicon.ico `(failed)::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

```
'use strict';
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    res.end('hello world');
    process.exit();
});
server.listen(port);
```

However when I attempt to send html information it throws an error immediately. `This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

```
'use strict';
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<header><title>hello world</title></header>');
    res.write('<body><h1>hello world</h1></body>');
    res.write('</html>');
    res.end();
    process.exit();
});
server.listen(port);
```

The server is so simple and I'm following very basic tutorials.  I'm not sure why favicon.ico is throwing a connection refused error in the first and why the second version fails immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers usually send multiple requests such as favion.ico, actual page etc., for HTML Pages.

Your code has `process.exit()` after receiving the first request.

You can either remove that line like below and it should work.

```
'use strict';
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<header><title>hello world</title></header>');
    res.write('<body><h1>hello world</h1></body>');
    res.write('</html>');
    res.end();
});
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: You are 100% correct.  I've been pulling my hair out for 2 hours and I never thought to remove `process.exit();`.

Comment: As an HTTP Server, you need to keep it running indefinitely. That's the basic idea. It's just that `process.exit()` exits the node process after serving the first request.

Comment: I was using `process.exit()` for testing. I wanted it to kick out after node sent the information.  But I never thought that would crash the whole thing.